# How to use Away3d Lite and FLARToolKiT for Augmented Reality Application

Tags: android, air, augmented-reality, away3d, flartoolkit

I haved succesfully implemented an Augmented Reality Application using the following softwares:

1. Adobe Flash Professional CS5
2. Adobe Air For Android
3. FLARToolKit
4. Papervision3D

Can you please let me know if any sources is available for me to find out how to start?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience few Android devices today have the power to even play Flash .flv at normal speed.  I'm curious as to whether the Android Flash player can take advantage of OpenGL; without it you haven't a prayer for Papervision3D.  FLAR takes compute as well..

I think you are ahead of your time :)  but I hope I'm wrong and look forward to this being possible.